# Magento: show admin product category in dropdown

Tags: magento, html-select, magento-1.9, objective-c-category

I want to show the category selection as a drop down instead of it rendering with a +sign
magento/admin/product/new product product category selection 
See below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: i think you did not read my question ! you saw screenshot and replied read question first !

Comment: No, I read the question. You are not asking a programming question. Have a read of what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: SEE bellow a champion answered

Comment: I see it, but even if someone answers it doesn't mean the question was on-topic.

Comment: haha i don,t need answer on your topic !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, You can just create bellow function under the block or helper with your module.

```
    function getCategoriesTreeView() {
    // Get category collection
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
    ->load()
    ->toArray();

   // Arrange categories in required array
   $categoryList = array();
   foreach ($categories as $catId => $category) {
    if (isset($category['name'])) {
        $categoryList[] = array(
            'label' => $category['name'],
            'level'  =>$category['level'],
            'value' => $catId
        );
    }
}
return $categoryList;
 }
```

Now its time for design, bellow is the code which will give you the category drop down.

```
<select id="categorylist" name="categorylist">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
<?php
$categoriesTreeView = getCategoriesTreeView();

foreach($categoriesTreeView as $value)
{
    $catName    = $value['label'];
    $catId      = $value['value'];
    $catLevel    = $value['level'];

    $space = '&nbsp;';
    for($i=1; $i<$catLevel; $i++){
        $space = $space."&nbsp;";
    }
    $catName = $space.$catName;

    ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $catIdIs; ?>"><?php echo $catName ?></option>
 <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: hi thank you very much ! can you please tell me exact file location where should i use this code